# DB2 on cloud:: ERROR: HWCSEC0009E: Failed to call state restful api

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I have created DB2 on Cloud (free Lite) service and tried to login to it using the service credentials that were generated. But after the login screen, it lands in user profile page (presumably for a password change for first time login), but it doesn't load the page completely and throws an error as below:

> HWCSEC0009E: Failed to call state restful api

I have tried deleting the service and recreating again using different service locations (like London and Dallas), but still get the same issue.

For example, I am getting this issue using below URLs :

https://dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-lon02-15.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443

(London)

https://dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-14.services.dal.bluemix.net/

(Dallas)

The error is visible when loading the page, such as below depending on the region you select,
https://dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-lon02-15.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443/console/#user/profile

or

https://dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-14.services.dal.bluemix.net/console/#user/profile

I have even tried using "incognito" browser as well.

FYI,
I did follow the initial part, login via cloud.ibm.com/login > cloud foundry services > click on my service-name. But clicking on "Open Console" keeps throwing error:

> {"trace":"xxxx","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0016E:
> Authentication failed for SSO. This may caused by failed to generate
> access token in console side using existing
> credentials.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}

So, i had to create Service Credentials and then use the direct https URL given there with the user name and password details to login/access DB2 on Cloud "Console".

Please advice.

Comment: I login via cloud.ibm.com/login > cloud foundry services > click on my service-name that I created > open console.

Comment: working for me. Try clearing browser cache/history/cookies, restart browser, and retry.

Comment: Thanks Mao for your advice. I have already tried clearing browser cache/history/cookies, restart browser, and retry couple of times and also tried using different browsers to eliminate single browser issue! Still no luck so far.

Comment: I use linux (ubuntu) and firefox . Which operating system , which browser?

Comment: I use Mac. I tried using Chrome, FireFox, Safari.

Comment: I have a Linux (RedHat) as well. I tried using Chrome on that as well, but same issue. So, doesn't look like my system or the browser issue!

Comment: If it is a general problem, others will report it (to IBM), given time.

Comment: A web console restart by IBM Cloud Support team resolved the issue. This issue can be closed.